# How to permanently, forever ignore thumbs.db on Subversion?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to have thumbs.db files completely and forever ignored by subversion, in all my repositries, in all their directories. Is that possible? If not, what's the next closest thing? I'm using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Settings > General > Global ignore pattern.

That should hide them in TortoiseSVN, if you also want to purge them from accidental versioning you'll need something more clever.

Comment: Keep in mind though, that this applies only for **you**; each developer on your team will have to repeat the same one-time change for it to apply to them as well.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer only works in tortoise, and each user must do it on their system.
The general solution is to add thumbs.db to the `svn:ignore` property and commit it - this will solve it for everyone with no fuss on their part.
The [svn redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) has some good info about `svn:ignore`